# MobaXterm: Log all NEW terminal activity in a separate file?

Tags: windows, logging, terminal

Is it possible (either directly or through a plugin) to log all new terminal activity?

To further explain, I have logging setup such that all terminal activity gets saved to a file in a directory of my choosing. So say I've typed out some commands & those are logged to the file. That's great. Now I want to be able to specify that all further commands typed in & whatever the result output shown on the terminal is, should be logged to a new file.

Does anyone know whether it's possible to switch log files easily?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible.
You can edit the session, goto Terminal settings -> Log Output Terminal to=
and provide your log file path. The you get all your session log files in that path

Comment: Tried this setting by giving path to a local directory and don't see any file there. I am usng V10.9. Are there any tips to make this work?

Comment: @cnu on v11.0 it works, i remember it working in older version as well.Once set try restart the session, you should see log files getting stored to the given path.

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to the image where to add the path.
[image: xterm screen shot]

Comment: I use version 21.1 and I am able to set the log file name, too. Using the default log file format, the logfile name contains the timestamp and therefore my different terminal windows write to different logfiles. This also already worked on version predecessing 21.2.

Answer (score -1):

This works for specific sessions or the top-level global configuration. I also wanted to know if there was a way to define the type of file output?  For example, when you get this same information manually by right-clicking on the session tab and select the "save terminal output" command, you can then choose the "Rich Text Document" or "Plain Text" under the "Save as type:" drop-down field before clicking the save button.  The file created by the auto logging is plain text.

Comment: Hi Erik, this answer is not really addressing the question. You can change the file formats but can you change the file. Perhaps update your answer to specifically address the question and how it can be achieved.